# Count items in array of array

Tags: arrays, core-data, swift4, nsfetchrequest

I have an array of arrays stored in core data as a "Transformable"

e.g.

```
colorArray = [[Red, Blue, Green], [Red], [Blue, Green], [Green], [Blue], [Blue, Green, Red]]
```

I want a function that counts the amount of times each colour appears in the core data attribute (colorArray) in total. So for the above data the function would print:

```
Red = 3
Blue = 4
Green = 4
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution with `NSCountedSet`.

- Flatten the array.
- Create the counted set from the array.
- Enumerate the set.

The example uses strings

```
let colorArray = [["Red", "Blue", "Green"], ["Red"], ["Blue", "Green"], ["Green"], ["Blue"], ["Blue", "Green", "Red"]]

let flattened = colorArray.reduce([], +)
let set = NSCountedSet(array: flattened)
for element in set {
    print("\(element) = \(set.count(for: element))")
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly if I set the array in the code to be:

     [["Red", "Blue", "Green"], ["Red"], ["Blue", "Green"], ["Green"], ["Blue"], ["Blue", "Green", "Red"]]

However, I can't retrieve the actual array that I want from core data. Do you know how to do this? I have it saved in an entity called "Item". The attribute name is colorArray and type is transformable

Comment: If it's a transformable, why can't you retrieve it?

Comment: I used `String` because I have – still –  no clue what the color names represent.